# tokbox Video conference with accept deny functionality

Tags: opentok, video-conferencing, tokbox

I am working on a video conference APP using TOKBOX(WEBRTC-javascript) for multiple users and got stuck in the functionality where user1 call user2 and user2 have the option to accept deny this call(like in skype).

**Need Help to implement this functionality**

I have all the users already connected in the session(room).

I had tried to save all the streams object in a array and then pass that saved object in the session.subscribe() function but it gives an error of 'call to a function of undefined'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you can try:
* you can have user 1 and user 2 both connect to their own sessions.
* When user1 "calls" user2, user1 leaves his own session and joins user2's session.
* user2 gets a connectionCreated event, in this event handler you can prompt user2 if he wants to accept or deny call.
* When user2 hits accept, he subscribes to user1's stream. If he hits deny, you can call [session.forceDisconnect](https://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/js/reference/Session.html#forceDisconnect) so that user1 is forced to disconnect from user2's session.
* User1 will get a sessionDisconnected event, and when that happens, connect him back to his original session.

Comment: Let me clarify my scenario/requirement: 'When user1 "calls" user2' means i have a single page with currently single session id  and all the users are online their doing text chat, and from this list user1 can click on user2 and user2 will have the notification to accept/deny his request. I think for this scenario i can not user diff session id.

Comment: each user can still have their own session id. when user1 'calls' user2, then disconnect user1 and user2 from that chatroom session, and then connect both users to user2's sessionid.

Comment: @VikasDuhan if you haven't already seen, there is a new OpenTok Starter Kit called [PresenceKit](https://github.com/opentok/presencekit-php) that has a very similar functionality implemented.